# iOS - How to send attachment using SOAP?

Tags: ios, iphone, soap, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest

I am using NSMutableURLRequest to upload parameters to server using SOAP API and it is working fine.

```
static NSString *URLString = @"http://www.myURL";
NSMutableURLRequest *request =
[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLString]];

[request addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"]; 
[request addValue:@"http://..." forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];

NSString *name = @"John";

NSString *parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                         @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://..../\">\n"
                         "<s:Body >\n"
                         "<name>%@</name>\n"
                         "</s:Body>\n"
                         "</s:Envelope>\n", name];
[request setHTTPBody:[parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

_myConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

Now I want to send a text file (attachment) along with the parameters.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi you can convert your file into `NSDATA` then  into `BASE64` String and add as parameter to your request body and after that at backend you can convert `BASE64` String to `Binary Data` and save it as text file.

**Encoding**

```
NSString *str=[[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"file.txt"];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:str];
NSString *base64String = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
NSLog(@"%@", base64String);
```

Here is the link for [BASE64 Conversion classes](https://github.com/nicklockwood/Base64)

Just add one more parameter

```
NSString *parameters = [NSString stringWithFormat:
                     @"<s:Envelope xmlns:s=\"http://..../\">\n"
                     "<s:Body >\n"
                     "<name>%@</name>\n"
                     "<fileData>%@</fileData>\n"   //Here is new parameter
                     "</GetChanges>\n"
                     "</s:Body>\n"
                     "</s:Envelope>\n", name, base64String];
```

Comment: I don't have access to the server-side. I have to send the file info in the following parameter: <not:NoteTxt>cid:note.txt</not:NoteTxt> and send the data with the call....what I am unable to figure out is, how am I supposed to send the file data with this call ??

Comment: it seems like you have to send text file's text. is it?

Comment: No. I have to send the file as an attachment.